# Angular 2 dynamic menu loading and routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am trying design a website. A user can have different roles such as admin,manager or employee which will be decided during login.The rest url returns the type of the user logging in .I want to load the view dynamically based on the type of the user.Dynamically i mean the side bar has to be loaded with menu specific to that user and also landing page has to be dynamic depending on the user.Please suggest me how to do it or please redirect me to proper resource.As this is the starting point i dont have any code samples to attach .Please help.Thanking in advance.

**Update**

as of now in have a login coponent that will redirect to my home page like this

```js
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

,and the home page menus are loaded from database like

```js
this.menuLoader.getFunctionalities(this.empId).subscribe(response => {
      this.roleArray=response;
      this.roleArray.forEach((element) => {
        this.funtionalities = element.functionList;
        console.log(element.functionList);
      });
    });//subscribe ends here
  }
```

and in html i have

```html
<li *ngFor = "let x of funtionalities" (click)="closeSidenav()"> <a class="item white"  [routerLink] = "'/home'+x.FunctionValue">{{ x.FunctionName.toUpperCase()  }}</a></li>
```

and i have the database structure like

```html
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59676398506d3c2e58feb5d2"),
    "role" : "admin",
    "functionList" : [ 
        {
            "FunctionName" : "Create CFT",
            "FunctionValue" : "/createCFT"
        }, 
        {
            "FunctionName" : "Update CFT",
            "FunctionValue" : "/updateCFT"
        }, 
        {
            "FunctionName" : "Add Employee",
            "FunctionValue" : "/addEmployee"
        }, 
        {
            "FunctionName" : "Add Resource",
            "FunctionValue" : "/addResource"
        }, 
        {
            "FunctionName" : "Add Employees-Excel",
            "FunctionValue" : "/addEmployeesExcel"
        }, 
        {
            "FunctionName" : "Add Holiday List",
            "FunctionValue" : "/holidayList"
        }, 
        {
            "FunctionName" : "Add Employees to CFT",
            "FunctionValue" : "/addEmployeeToCft"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is that you did in code. please update it to post. the question is too broad

Comment: updated the question aravind.

Answer (score 0):

Your property `functionList` contains the content for routing which is not used in the `*ngFor` modify as below,

```
<li *ngFor = "let x of funtionalities.functionList" (click)="closeSidenav()"> 
     <a class="item white"  [routerLink] = "'/home'+x.FunctionValue">
          {{ x.FunctionName.toUpperCase()  }}
     </a>
</li>
```

Comment: that was assigned to funtionalities in the component code,And the question was about how to do the dynamic loading.I think the method i am following is not the right way to go aboug it.

Comment: On trying this did you get any error. All the route definitions must be in the `RouterModule` did you have these definitions?

Comment: i did not get any error ,and i have a routing module defined as wel.That isnt the question.The question is 'what is the method  used to do the above explained question.'Because the method i am using ,i really dont think thats the preffered method to be used

Comment: why are you having `(click)` method in the `li` tag? **So, when you click on a hyperlink the parent `closeSideNav()` might be executed instead of routing**

Comment: thats for displaying side bar .If i click on that ,respective route will be loaded in the body section.Close side nav just has just a jquery function to close the sidenav.Routing is working as expected'

Comment: remove that and see it must route or log some errors

Comment: i Think you misunderstood the question aravind.The app is working fine as expected.My question is "Is this the right way to go about it or do we have a better way for displaying menus and route based on the role of the user who logs in"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149291/discussion-between-aravind-and-vikk).